# How do I correctly build a string with unicode chars to use with pyapns?

Tags: php, iphone, json, unicode, push

I am using pyapns server to send Iphone push messages. I connect with the pyapns server using PHP.

When I send a message with unicode characters such as `{\"data\":\"\u094d\"}` I get the following error response:

> 8002 Reason: 'Can't deserialize input: not well-formed (invalid token): line X, column Y'

If I change the data to `{\"data\":\"ABC\"}` everything works fine.

I am using xmlrpc to encode the strings using `php_xmlrpc_encode`.

Anyone know how I should format my unicode characters for this to work?

Comment: I think that the problem is in the backslashes. Not sure which one, never did something like that

Comment: try something like that: {\"data\":\"\\u094d\"}. Note the double backslash. The problem might be that it was trying to do \u instead of taking the whole \u094d as a string

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm too stuck on this problem. :(

Comment: I'm trying to push Japanese characters using PHP and pyAPNS but not able to :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a second backslash to that unicode character:

```
{\"data\":\"\\u094d\"}
```

The PHP interpreter will not recognize the \u command, but your JSON parser will (or should have to according to JSON spec).

Comment: I'm not using JSON but simple messages that are pushed using pyAPNS.
I tried sending this 働 どう dō, はたら(く) and used php_xmlrpc_encode but it says can't deserialize..

Comment: When I try to send these chars, it says
An error occurred: Code: 8002 Reason: 'Can't deserialize input: not well-formed (invalid token): line 16, column 39'

Comment: The point is that you have to encode your string to UTF-8 correctly. It seems that you try to send unencoded strings, which can lead to parsing problems like you are experiencing right now, especially when you are nesting such escaping techniques. You will need to know which value you are displaying (therefore unified) before rendering the template, maybe even at DB level.

Comment: to parse your (what looks like) JSON data, I'm pretty sure your library uses a JSON parser... So it should deal with values like \uXXXX, but you'll need double quotes for the backslash. Anyway, if you could bring me some extended code examples, I'm sure I can explain it to you!

Comment: Please have a look at the code I posted as a separate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm trying to compose the message and push to pyAPNS server.

Thanks

```
$echoString = new xmlrpcmsg ( 'notify', array(
                            php_xmlrpc_encode($APNS_APP_ID),      //app_id
                            php_xmlrpc_encode($deviceToken),     //device_tocke
                            php_xmlrpc_encode(array("aps" => array(
                                                'alert' => "働 どう dō, はたら(く)", 
                                                'sound' => 'newMsg.wav',
                                                'badge' => 1,
                                                'feedid' => $target_nick,
                                                'fromid' => $target_nick
                                             )))
                            )     );
```

Comment: Where do you get the php_xmlrpc_encode() function from? It does not exist in php: http://www.php.net/php_xmlrpc_encode

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the xmlrpc internal encoding to utf8:

```
$GLOBALS['xmlrpc_internalencoding'] = 'UTF-8';
```

I believe the default is ISO-8859-1.
I was trying to send cute little emojis to my pyapns server with no luck, but this did the trick.